# Shell Replace a string in a file

Tags: sed, awk, cut

I have an array of url's. I have a script to open them and if they are opening up without any error , show the status as running else not running. Now I want to replace corresponding status of url ({ABC_Service_Status}) in a html with this status. Where do I place my sed statement and how to cut just the `ABCService` from the url

```
urlArray=('http://server:port/ABCservice/services/ABCservice?wsdl' 'http://server:port/DEFservice/services/DEFservice?wsdl')       
for url in "${urlArray[@]}"
 do 
   result=`curl $url | head -1`    
    if (echo $result | grep '<?xml' >/dev/null 2>&1); then           
          echo Running
    else
        echo Not Running
     fi    
done
```

**Current Output:**

```
Running
Not Running
```

I have a html file with the below content (version.html)

```
 <tr><td>ABCService</td><td>12.11.0</td><td>{ABCService_Status}</td>/tr>
 <tr><td>DEFService</td><td>12.11.0</td><td>{DEFService_Status}</td>/tr>
```

**Desired output after replacing:**

```
 <tr><td>ABCService</td><td>12.11.0</td><td>Running</td>/tr>
 <tr><td>DEFService</td><td>12.11.0</td><td>Not Running</td>/tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine variables and string literals in sed commands:

```
for service in ABCService DEFService
    do sed --in-place s/\{${service}_Status\}/REPLACEMENT/ version.html
done
```

You will be parsing the whole file for each service, though.